# Erro ao escrever IF e Else no jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if, else

estou começando a me aventurar agora pelo mundo do desenvolvimento e bateu uma dúvida ao utilizar IF e Else.

O código abaixo está OK

```
    <select id="course_list" >
      <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('tribe_events_cat=petroleo-e-gas'); ?>
         <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <option value="course_<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#course_list").on('change', function(){
        $('.course_item').hide();
        $('#' + this.value).show();

    });
</script>
```

Mas quando tento aprimorar o código e para voltar a mostrar todos os cursos, tudo parou de funcionar.

```
<select id="course_list" >
        <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('tribe_events_cat=petroleo-e-gas'); ?>
        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <option value="all-posts" >
            Mostrar Todos
        </option>
        <option value="course_<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#course_list").on('change', function(){

        if {
            $('.course_item').hide();
            $('#' + this.value).show();
           }

        else

            $('.course_item=').show();


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: O que queres verificar no `if`? o `if` tem de ter uma condição a verificar dentro de parenteses: `if (algo a verificar){ // fazer algo`

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Seu código possui um erro de sintaxe no no bloco "if else".
Para corrigir você precisará colocar uma condição a ser testada dentro do if. Por exemplo:

```
if(ALGUMA_VARIAVEL == CONDICAO) {
    $('.course_item').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();
} else
    $('.course_item=').show();
```

Se a condição for satisfeita em algum momento, seu bloco 'if' será executado, caso contrário, será sempre executado o 'else'.

Comment: Sergio valeu pelas dicas o texto foi ótimo e Lucas irei tentar fazer o código funcionar mais tarde, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.